# Grouping fields into Drupal block to appear in its node

Tags: views, entities

I have a content type with several fields. I need to group some fields of each node into a block. The block will contain the fields values of that particular node only.

[image]

In this layout, AAA is a photo slider displaying some photos of that node. On the right, BBB is a block containing some fields. I am trying to create this BBB as a block.

Initially I thought this could be done with the fieldgroup module, just only a matter of configuring the fieldgroup setting for < div >? And in that form, this question is similar to earlier ones, and has also been well answered.

But on further research, this doesn't work. In the diagram, AAA and BBB are siblings. If the fields in BBB have a < div > but still under the larger container and not in their own block, then it can't float with the other AAA block since they are not siblings.

Therefore, I need not only to group with < div > for the fields but indeed must wrap these fields into a Drupal block. How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate. The requirements are completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) (DS) module. Initial research cleares lingering doubt on performance and it turns out that the solution is quite simple.

[DS](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) divides the Content type display into several *panels (Left, Right, Top, etc)* and fields can be moved accordingly. Each panel is a `<div>` - exactly what I need. But how to put the slider there? Cannot just set it up like a block, which will put it outside of the DS area and thus not sibling to Right panel.

Found out that DS can make a block into a field and as such it can be moved into the Left panel. And thus solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to display settings for your content type and select div under format and save it. The contents are then wrapped in a div. 
[image: div wrapping contents]

see here in firebug [image: firebug showing contents inside div]

Note: You can also use a template (.tpl) file for your content type and there you can wrap your desired contents inside a div.

Answer (score 0):

See this module this will help you to fashion group of specific fields in views itself [Views Fieldset](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_fieldsets)